# jpeg encode: what happens if source buffer data changes when encoding

Tags: jpeg, encode

I have a question about detail process of jpeg encoder, it's difficult to explain and make experiment:

I have a source image buffer which contains RGB image, 
it changes very frequently (but visibly no sudden big change), for example:

2014/12/19 13:16:00.000000us  my face
2014/12/19 13:16:00.000010us  my face (turning smile)
2014/12/19 13:16:00.000020us  my face (turning more smile)
... ...

If i pass the buffer to jpeg encoder such as libjpeg, but please note that:

---

WITHOUT COPY source image buffer to encoder (no snapshot to encoder)

---

What is result image of jpeg encoder ???
1. My face but expression is undetermined ?
2. or Garbled image even not like a face?
3. or just crashes because some data it reference changes when next time use?

I do not care source image buffer integrity.

Comment: So why dont you try and see?

Comment: To do this experiment i have to reconstruct my program completely (currently is ffmpeg.exe+mylib, big source image buffer are copied many times, it costs surprising CPU time).   Before i spend time to reconstruct program, i just want to know is the plan correct.